Enabling xwayland-allow-grabs in dconf to workaround "desktop search" possibly increased responsiveness system wide
Somewhat recently in my Ubuntu 23.10 install, I came across a bug/feature where every time I used a keyboard shortcut (like Ctrl+Alt+T), nothing would happen and instead the desktop would be searched for the whichever alphanumeric was in the shortcut (i.e. the letter T). It persisted across programs with all shortcuts not working as they should with most just being ignored (with the exception of Steam/full-screen programs iirc).
Anyway, I solved this issue by enabling the dconf setting:
org/gnome/mutter/wayland/xwayland-allow-grabs
I could then use all my shortcuts as  before; however, oddly enough my entire computer seemed to be faster. Before enabling this; searching a large .pdf for a single word would take a minute or more, now it takes mere seconds (likely as it should be). Windows load faster, seemingly smoother gameplay, etc. Apparently this bug had been bogging down my system for years.
This could have been a result of the many restarts (and first ever log-outs) I did when looking through GNOME extensions, but I only noticed the change after enabling allow-grabs. I also particularly remember .pdf searches always being slow even before upgrading to 23.10 and getting into GNOME extensions. So I'm fairly certain it was that dconf setting.
Any idea as to why this is? I vaguely recall an old post about a wayland bug with similar issues but iirc it was pretty old. I'm pleasantly confused (aka: curious) especially with the .pdf search function becoming helluh more speedy for the first time since install.
Thanks.
*P.S. I am referring to the search function in Document Viewer, Ubuntu's default .pdf app.

Desktop search "function" that disables shortcuts is fixed by enabling the dconf setting:
org/gnome/mutter/wayland/xwayland-allow-grabs
